# How can we get Facebook Page List in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully logged user to Facebook using Facebook Graph API and now i need to fetch the user's Facebook page list (`page status` is already changed to `Published`).

My code looks like :

```
 (void)checkLoginWithFacebook {
    // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {


        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked

        [self getListOfPages];
    }
    else
    {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for basic_info permissions when opening a session

        // This will bypass the ios6 integration since it does not allow for a session to be opened
        // with publish only permissions!


        FBSession* sess = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",nil]];

        [FBSession setActiveSession:sess];
        [sess openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView) completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {

             [[AppDelegate appDel] sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];


             if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed)
             {

                 NSLog(@"session closed");
                 return ;
             }

             [self getListOfPages];
         }];
    }

}


    (void)getListOfPages {
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/accounts"
                              completionHandler:^(
                                                  FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                  id result,
                                                  NSError *error
                                                  ) {
                                  /* handle the result */
                                  NSLog(@"pages result: %@ ",result);
                              }];
    }
```

***Response:***

```
pages result: {
                data = (); 
              }
```

Please Advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you requested the `manage_pages` permission from the respective user through the login dialog? The code you posted look ok IMHO, I think you see an empty result because of the missing permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have missed the "manage_pages" permission.

Comment: It is working in only one condition. I have created Facebook App ID. So, I am able to fetch my list of pages. But other user is not able to fetch their pages. Please advice.

Comment: Please read the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review You need to go through Facebook Review because you're using an extended permission

Comment: Hope, This is helpful for me. Thanks.